# Special characters in agetty.c

Tags: linux, authentication

The `agetty.c` treats some characters like `@` , as special . When an `@` symbol is entered at the login prompt , it removes all the text. Does it have anything to do with the security or it is as per the design they are treated special characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at the source, you'll see that both <kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> are synonyms for the line kill character.

This is a historic relic from the days when TTY line discipline used control characters like NAK (Ctrl-U) for flow control. Although there are few systems that still exist which impose hardware limitations on the usable character set, historical relics like `@` still persist for the 3 devices out there where you can't send an actual Ctrl-U and have it received as a 0x15. You will also see the same feature with <kbd>#</kbd> as a historical synonym for <kbd>BS</kbd>.

Even if you ignore the vintage devices that are so limited, old habits, particularly in getty and stty persist because "we've always done it that way".

Comment: So basically it is not for security reasons , but because of "we've always done it that way" ?

Comment: I can think of no security considerations that would rely upon special behavior of `@` and the historical reason is true.

Comment: `agetty` from util-linux used to have the special characters `@` and `#`. They were removed in the version 2.23 (2013). See `--erase-chars string` and `--erase-chars string`: https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/e828630a16c7c31bfbce228d6993c1cff7088152/term-utils/agetty.8.adoc#options

Answer (score 1):

> Macro: int VKILL This is the subscript for the KILL character in the
>   special control character array. termios.c_cc[VKILL] holds the
>   character itself. The KILL character is recognized only in canonical
>   input mode. When the user types the kill character, the entire
>   contents of the current line of input are discarded. The kill
>   character itself is discarded too.
>
> The KILL character is usually C-u.[more...](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_368.html)

Another one explaining `@`:

> As a historical note, the erase character was originally #, and the
>   kill character was originally @. These assignments go back to the
>   olden days, when terminals printed with real ink on real paper and
>   made lots of noise. However, I'm told that there are some modern
>   systems on which these settings are still the default [more...](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch05_08.htm)